# Audio device in python, in case of various ways to run the script

Tags: python, linux, shell, audio, debian-based

[Intro]

OS: Raspbian Jessie; 
Device: Raspberry pi 3

I wrote a python-script, that plays audio files via vlc (python vlc bindings).
Next, I wrote a bash script, that runs python-script.
Next, I added the bash-script to autorun, using crontab.

Everything was working, everything was playing.

[main part]

Next, I decided to test external audio card.

Everything was working out of the box.
When I pulled out the sound card and connected to the headphone jack on the raspberry - the problems started. 
Now. when I run bash script, catch next errors:

**cannot open ALSA device "default": No such file or directory**

BUT if I perform the exactly same actions (as in bash script) manually, everything works as it should.

mystic!

bash script looks like:

```
cd /app/path
sudo python2 app.py
cd /
```

python script:

```
import vlc
a = vlc.MediaPplayer(file)
a.play()
```

Comment: show us the python code inside the app.py file please

Comment: @dopstar I updated the first message